# SignalR with Service bus in Azure WebSites

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-web-app-service, azureservicebus

I would like to use Azure Website to deploy a website with signalR, using Azure ServiceBus. Is it possible ? Or i have to use azure roles ?

FYI, got this error :

```
Unable to resolve the instance index of this role. Make sure Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll is deployed with your application.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work today but it will when the next version of scaleout comes out in 1.1.